# Spam link inserted into my GitHub pages website

Tags: javascript, html, css, security, github

I have a [personal website](https://fionn.xyz/) deployed by GitHub pages. Last night I noticed a spam link on the front page. The site is stored in a private repo, and deployed to a custom domain name with GitHub SSH encryption.

[image]

Some things I've tried to do to fix the issue:

- No one has committed any code to my repo.
- I've searched the whole codebase for any reference to the URL or `Bitcoin Rush`. Nothing.
- I've edited some content on the site, it's deployed correctly to the live internet but the spam link is still there.
- I've tested if the link is present on other browsers and devices, it is.

If anyone has suggestions for what else I could try, and what the underlying issue is so I can prevent it happening again in the future.

Comment: Alas hackers are many and have great imagination. I have just today had to again replace my .htaccess since it was overwritten with one that redirects to medicine adverts.
I have no idea how they manage to overwrite a write protected file on my server, but somewhere in my or my provider's system is a backdoor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your html, there is this script:

```html
<script src="https://www.retainable.io/assets/retainable/rss-embed/retainable-rss-embed.js"></script>
```

which embed this javascript content:

```js
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    if (document.querySelector('p')) {
        document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML + '<div><a href="redacted">Bitcoin Rush</a></div>';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML + '<div><a href="redacted">Bitcoin Rush</a></div>';
    }
} else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
        if (document.querySelector('p')) {
            document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = document.querySelector('p').innerHTML + '<div><a href="redacted">Bitcoin Rush</a></div>';
        } else {
            document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML + '<div><a href="redacted">Bitcoin Rush</a></div>';
        }
    });
}
```

My guess is that it was supposed to be javascript code used to load the RSS feed from the configuration:

```html
<div id="retainable-rss-embed" 
    data-rss="https://medium.com/feed/@F_Delahunty"
    data-maxcols="3" 
    data-layout="grid" 
    data-poststyle="inline" 
    data-readmore="Read the rest" 
    data-buttonclass="btn btn-primary" 
    data-offset="-100">
</div>
```

But it seems retainable.io was hacked, any url like `https://www.retainable.io/test` returns the hacked content

A quick solution is not to use retainable.io

Comment: Thank you! I remove the script and all is well. It shows the danger of randomly trusting web services. Are you aware of anywhere I could report retainable as a malware site? (I've already reported it to google safe browsing).

Comment: @F.D you're welcome,it seems retainable still references retainable.io in one of their example [here](https://www.retainable.app/embed-your-medium-blog). But in the others, they use twilik.com which doesn't look compromised: https://www.twilik.com/assets/retainable/rss-embed/retainable-rss-embed.js. Maybe, you can use the contact form in retainable.app to reach to them.There is also [the source code](https://github.com/chrisj74/vue-rss-blog) which has [few occurence](https://github.com/chrisj74/vue-rss-blog/search?q=retainable.io) of the compromised url.Maybe you can create an issue about this

Comment: @F.D maybe you can use [the github project](https://github.com/chrisj74/vue-rss-blog) to generate the js and css, and embed them in your website if you still want the RSS feed

Comment: Thanks! I did both of those things, hopefully, they respond and others don't have this issue.

Comment: A colleague had the same issue today - found your issue on github for retainable. Good work.